# RoomDatabase crashes during migration even though Database set to fallbackToDestructiveMigration

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

We are seeing more crashes in Fabric during RoomDatabase migration. Any suggestion to fix the issue

RoomDatabase initialization:

```
companion object {
        fun createNotesDatabase(androidContext: Context): NotesDatabase {
            try {
                return Room.databaseBuilder(androidContext, NotesDatabase::class.java, "notesdb")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("NotesDatabase", "exception")
            }
        }
    }
```

**Stack trace for the exception:**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A migration from 1 to 4 was required but not found. Please provide the necessary Migration path via RoomDatabase.Builder.addMigration(Migration ...) or allow for destructive migrations via one of the RoomDatabase.Builder.fallbackToDestructiveMigration* methods.
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade + 97(RoomOpenHelper.java:97)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onUpgrade + 133(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:133)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked + 400(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:400)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase + 298(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:298)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase + 96(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:96)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase + 54(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:54)
       at com.limemobile.notes.data.local.NotesDatabase_Impl.clearAllTables + 280(NotesDatabase_Impl.java:280)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 1 of three things either:-

1. Provide the necessary Migration path(s), which entails adding suitable migration routines or :-
2. Override the **onDestructiveMigration** method using a **RoomDatabase.Callback** method invoked by using the **.addCallback(the_CallBack_method)**, or :-
3. Change the version back to 1 along with deleting the database (uninstall the App or deleting the App's data would delete the database). This would then not detect a version change and thus not expect either option 1 or 2.

Which option would depend upon information not provided, you may wish to read [Understanding migrations with Room](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929).

## Additional

The following is an example where the onDestructiveMigration method is overridden to do nothing (the database tables are effectively cleared of any data but will exist).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAppDB = Room.databaseBuilder(
            this,
            AppDatabase.class,
            "the_database"
    )
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .addCallback(dbCallback) //<<<<<<<<<<< defines the callback to be called
            .build();
    }
}

//<<<<<<<<<< The callback
private RoomDatabase.Callback dbCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onCreate(db);
        //.......... code here to do anything required when the database is created ..........//
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        //.......... code here to do anything required when the database is opened ..........//
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestructiveMigration(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onDestructiveMigration(db);
        //.......... code here to do anything required when the database has effectively been recreated (tables would have been built) ..........//
    }
};
```

- Overriding onCreate and onOpen isn't required. However, if there are no applicable migrations AND the database has been built with **.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()**, then the **onDestructiveMigration** method should be overidden (even if to do nothing, which may be suitable in some situations) as it will be called. **i.e. this is why it crashed**

Comment: Thanks Mike for the suggestion. I am still wondering why would it crash only one some device only. I will add callback and update here.